# How do I disable mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, here-api

**How do I disable the mouse scroll over a map using HERE-API?**

When I'm using a mobile device and the map is larger than the device screen, I need to disable the scroll feature.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when asking a question here, be sure to include a MCVE code in order for others to answer your specific question
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what u really want but you can use overflow:hidden in the element containing the here api there is alot of other methods including JavaScript but I am not familiar with this api , what about e.preventDefaults() on a scrolling event ? I will post the code if u need it and please post your code so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line of code:

```
map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.MouseWheel"));
```